# Apache reverse proxy AH01597: could not open mime types config file

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache-2.4, mime-type

I'm trying to configure Apache HTTP server 2.4 as a reverse proxy on RHEL 7 server. When Apache starts up it complains in its log file (`/var/log/httpd/error_log`):

```
 AH01597: could not open mime types config file /etc/httpd/conf/mime.types.
```

I'm surprised it cares about MIME types, as I do not want it to serve files from the file-system at  all. How can I configure Apache HTTP server so it does not demand a mime types configuration **or** which additional packages (RPMs) do I need to install to provide correct MIME types information.

Comment: Try to remove `TypesConfig` directive http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#typesconfig

Comment: mime.types are loaded by default to provide the correct mime for most types of files, all configurations by default should have it, every installation should come with them, just point or make sure the file is not corrupted, it won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I had based my Apache configuration file on the example that Red Hat provided. I included the command

```
 Include conf.modules.d/00-base.conf
```

as I thought leaving out any *base* modules would lead to Bad Things.

But the Red Hat supplied `conf.modules.d/00-base.conf` files loads numerous modules, few of which are required for a reverse proxy. In particular, it loads the `mod_mime` module, which needs a MIME types configuration file.

Replacing that `Include` command with individual `LoadModule` commands for the few modules I need eliminated the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @ezra-s mentioned mime.types file should come with installation. For my case it is located at /etc directory. So I just solved the same problem by copying the mime.types files from /etc directory to /etc/httpd/conf/

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by setting the wrong `ServerRoot` - do not confuse it (as I did) with `DocumentRoot`.

- `ServerRoot` - apache installation dir (and base dir for related logs, pidfiles, or mime.types etc.)
- `DocumentRoot` - web dir